# php: exclude dates from a date range

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude certain dates from a date range I've set up. The date range works fine like so:

```
<?php $newBegin = new DateTime('6/30/2010');
$newEnd = new DateTime('7/12/2010');
$newEnd = $newEnd->modify( '+1 day' );

$newDaterange = new DatePeriod($newBegin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $newEnd);

foreach($newDaterange as $newDate){
    echo $newDate->format("jnY") . " ";
} ?>
```

Which prints the results like so:

```
3062010 172010 272010 372010 472010 572010 672010 772010 872010 972010 1072010 1172010 1272010
```

But the client will need to exclude certain dates from each date range, so I'd preferably like to input the dates like so: `7/2/2010 7/4/2010 8/4/2010` and exclude them from the date range. Is this at all possible? I'm not looking to exclude weekends or such, I can do that, just input a set of dates and exclude them from a date range. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update:

As @hek2mgl asked for this, I've added a `var_dump()` of `get_field('test_select'));`

```
var_dump(get_field('test_select'));
```

Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "7/2/2010" [1]=> string(8) "
```

---

Full code (not working):

```
$newBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '6/30/2010');
$newEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '7/12/2010');
$newEnd = $newEnd->modify( '+1 day' );

$exclude = array();

// stores dates like so: 7/2/2010 7/3/2010
foreach(get_field('test_select') as $datestring) {
    $exclude []= new DateTime($datestring);
}

$newDaterange = new DatePeriod($newBegin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $newEnd);

foreach($newDaterange as $newDate){
    if(!in_array($newDate, $exclude)) {
        echo $newDate->format("jnY") . " ";
    }   
}
```

Comment: one piece of advice -- don't use potentially ambiguous date formats. `7/12/2010` may be July 12th to you, but to me it means 7th of December. And beware that ambiguous input can result in PHP assuming the wrong value. If possible, always use a non-ambiguous date format inside your code. If not possible, use `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()`, with the format specified explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to exclude several dates within a range using the `DatePeriod` class. But you can use `in_array()` together with `DateTime` objects. This can lead to code like this:

```
$newBegin = new DateTime('6/30/2010');
$newEnd = new DateTime('7/12/2010');
$newEnd = $newEnd->modify( '+1 day' );

$exclude = array(
    new DateTime('7/2/2010'),
    new DateTime('7/4/2010'),
    new DateTime('8/4/2010')
);

$newDaterange = new DatePeriod($newBegin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $newEnd);

foreach($newDaterange as $newDate){
    if(!in_array($newDate, $exclude)) {
        echo $newDate->format("jnY") . " ";
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
3062010 172010 372010 572010 672010 772010 872010 972010 1072010 1172010 1272010
```

---

Update:

In the comments you've asked how to translate an incoming list of date strings into `DateTime` objects which can be used in the `$exclude` array.

Example:

```
$exclude = array();

// stores dates like so: 7/2/2010 7/3/2010
foreach(get_field('test_select') as $datestring) {
    $exclude []= new DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', $datestring);
}
```

That's it. :)

Comment: thank you so much! this is nearly perfect, there's just one small thing, as the excluded dates (in the array) will be entered in the front end by the user, not the back end like the example above, is it possible for `new DateTime('7/2/2010'),` to be `get_field('test_select');` with the date entered in the `test_select` field by the user?

Comment: If `test_select` contains a date string parseble by `DateTime` use `new DateTime(get_field('test_select'));`

Comment: nice one, that worked! I've tweaked it a little bit, final question I promise, the `test_select` field now prints an array of dates. e.g. `echo implode(' ', get_field('test_select'));` displays dates like so: `7/2/2010 7/3/2010` is it possible to exclude these from the date range? I'm still pretty new to php so I'm not 100% sure how it would be written...

Comment: not quite, `get_field('test select')` returns blank so nothing is being excluded. I'm using this select field: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/ to choose an array. Thus `echo implode(' ', get_field('test_select'));` returns `7/2/2010 7/3/2010`. Is there any way of combining this with your example? p.s. thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: can you edit your question and add the output from `var_dump(get_field('test_select'));` ?

Comment: I'd corrected the typo before, still didn't seem to work. Just returns all the daterange. I've updated my question at the bottom with all the code...

Comment: Please do not update my answer. Update your question! Have a look at the vardump. The second string is empty. This is a problem. Also check my update. I'm using `createFromFormat` now.

Comment: apologies, that was an accident, now corrected...and that new code has worked! Thank you so much, much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, fine! gave you +1 for using `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod`. Thats *the* way how to do it in PHP! ;)

Comment: haha cheers! I'm still learning php, I'll get there in the end ;)